# ¿como hacer un SELECT de dos campos diferentes de una misma tabla en una sola columna en Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Buen día, estoy haciendo una consulta necesito realizar un select de 2 campos de una misma tabla pero dentro de una sola columna columna, es decir

```
SELECT desc_equipo, serialnro, serialmac from producto
```

desc_equipo es digamos el campo que almacena el nombre o descripción del producto, dependiendo del equipo, algunos tienen serialnro pero no tienen serialmac, otros tienen serialmac pero no tienen serialnro, entonces lo que me piden hacer es poner todos los datos, de serialnro y serialmac en una sola columna. He probado de varias formas pero me fallan todas.

¿Hay una forma de resolver esta duda?

Gracias de antemano

[image: Lo que tengo]

Comment: Y hay veces que un registro tiene ambos valores? `serialnro` y `serialmac`? Que quieres hacer entonces? *He probado de varias formas pero me fallan todas*: Puedes especificar tus intentos? Esto ayuda a aclarar tu pregunta.

Comment: no, ningún producto tiene ambos datos.

Comment: probé como un Where serialmac is not null or serialnro is not null, también probé con un subquery en el where tipo where serialnro in (select serialnro from producto where serialmac is not null and serialmac <> '  ')

Comment: Me parece interesante la condición en tu intento: `serialmac <> ' '`. ¿Significa esto que cuando una de las columnas *no tiene valor*, que no es siempre `null`? ¿Que a veces tiene un espacio? Espero que no sea el caso, es un poco raro eso. Pero si es el caso, sería bueno aclararlo, porque esto afecta las soluciones posibles.

Comment: o sea que a veces los que usan el sistema dejan un espacio en blanco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumiendo que `serialnro` y `serialmac` son del mismo tipo, y que solo uno de los 2 tiene un valor que no es `null` a la vez, entonces puedes usar `coalesce` para devolver el valor que no está a `null`:

```
select desc_equipo,
       coalesce(serialnro, serialmac) as serial
  from product
```

**Edicion**

> o sea que a veces los que usan el sistema dejan un espacio en blanco

Es una lástima que tengas espacios mezclados con `null` para representar un valor inexistente. Pero si este es el caso, puedes corregir la consulta por medio de un `trim` adicional que convierte los espacios vacíos en `null`, para que el `coalesce` funcione correctamente:

```
select desc_equipo,
       coalesce(trim(serialnro), serialmac) as serial
  from product
```

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para manejar un espacio.

Comment: gracias, funcionó

Answer (score 2):

Siento que la estructura de tu tabla es la incorrecta, si todos los productos tienen un serial pero unos son nro y otros son mac, entonces beberías tener una columna para el serial y otra columna para indicar si es mro o mac, tus columnas serian:

```
SERIAL VARCHAR2
SERIAL_TYPE VARCHAR2
```

y podrías agregar un constraint a la columna de Serial Type para que solamente acepte los valores que tu definas

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD
CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_SERIAL_TYPE_CHK CHECK (PRODUCT_SERIAL IN ('MAC','NRO'))
```

De esta manera eliminarias tus problemas con los espacios en blanco y nulos, cualquier duda estoy a tus órdenes.

Saludos!

Comment: eso hemos sugerido pero los jefes tienen su forma de manejar la base de datos, serialnro lo utilizan para decodificadores y serialmac para los modems, no entiendo por qué no ponen eso en un mismo campo si no va a afectar las operaciones, más bien afecta a programar las consultas.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar:

```
SELECT desc_equipo, TRIM(NVL(serialnro, ' ') || ' ' || NVL(serialmac, ' ')) AS serial
  FROM producto
```

En caso de que en un registro existan ambos, aparecerán concatenados.

Comment: El `nvl(columna, '')` es redundante. Oracle no tiene el concepto de una cadena vacía. Esta se convierte automaticamente en `null`.  De modo que el `nvl` resultaría en `null`.

Comment: @sstan ¡Ah! Cierto.